# save data in excel to worksheet to be over written or loaded later

Tags: vba, excel

I have a work book that I am trying to take some inserted data and save it on a new row for new data. But if the first cell of that entered data equals another cell in that same column than i want to over write that previously saved data with the newly entered data.

```
Sub SmartHBD_Save()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StoredJobs As Worksheet
Dim JobNumber As Integer
JobNumber = Sheets("Stored Jobs").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Stored Jobs").Range("B4:B" & JobNumber)
Set StoredJobs = Worksheets("Stored Jobs")
If c.Value = B2 Then
    StoredJobs.Range("B2:AO2").Copy
    StoredJobs.Cells(JobNumber, 1).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else
    StoredJobs.Range("B2:AO2").Copy
    StoredJobs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next c

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I had it working to save data on a new row but when I tried to get it to overwrite data it stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested:

```
Sub SmartHBD_Save()

    Dim StoredJobs As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim f As Range, theJob

    Set StoredJobs = Worksheets("Stored Jobs")
    lastRow = StoredJobs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    theJob = StoredJobs.Range("B2").Value

    'find the current job if it exists
    Set f = StoredJobs.Range("B4:B" & lastRow).Find(what:=theJob, lookat:=xlWhole)

    'if not found, use the next empty row
    If f Is Nothing Then Set f = StoredJobs.Range("B" & (lastRow + 1))

    'B1:AO1 is *relative* to f.EntireRow
    f.EntireRow.Range("B1:AO1").Value = StoredJobs.Range("B2:AO2").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome that works and makes a lot more sense that the mess i came up with.